# Take out the index.php string in the url in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I need to hide/remove the index.php in the URL's of my application in CodeIgniter. I proved something i saw in a tutorial on youtube but in didn't work, the solution was writing something in my .htaccess.

Here's my repository:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/CodeIgniter/tree/master/CodeIgniter

And here you have my .htaccess file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.")$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mode_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

http://pastebin.com/eCU5UgL0

Comment: Have you enabled `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled.

Comment: Try when `RewriteBase` is added too. If in root of `public_html` -> `RewriteBase /` or if in some subdirectory -> `RewriteBase /subdir/#don't forget ending slash`

Comment: I write that on .htaccess?

Comment: Don't simply dump links to your code.   Please take the time to cut & paste the relevant code into your OP.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I use pastebin for sharing my code because whenever i try to paste it here, it gets all messed up and it's hard to read.

Comment: That's not acceptable... everyone else seems to be able to figure it out.  When you use links, they eventually go dead and the posting becomes useless to others.

Comment: @FelipePino http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my `.htaccess` to take out `index.php` from the URL.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The RewriteRule `^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` should be `^(.*)$` not `^(.")$`

Check the rule. Wish it helps.

`^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1` represents whatever you requested, redirect it to the `index.php` file which can handle the passing parameters.

In regex, `.` means anything; `*` means 0 or more times.

Comment: This did it. Thanks!